# count total text in column delimiter by '' , ''

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some kind of this table

```
No   app_list
1    ['com.lenovo.anyshare.gps', 'com.UCMobile.intl'] 
2    []
3    ['com.rarlab.rar', 'com.kreditpintar', 'com.whatsapp']
```

and I want to count that app_list, and be like this

```
No  app_list                                                      count
1   ['com.lenovo.anyshare.gps', 'com.UCMobile.intl']              2
2   []                                                            0
3   ['com.rarlab.rar', 'com.kreditpintar', 'com.whatsapp']        3
```

is there any way to get it done like that ?
thank you

Comment: Are they strings or lists?

Comment: ...or elements of a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Going by the tags I'm just going to assume this is a pandas dataframe... still should be specified in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the length of each list in the row and add it to a new column:

```py
###### Recreating OP's dataframe ##########
import pandas as pd
No = [1, 2, 3]
app_list = [['com.lenovo.anyshare.gps', 'com.UCMobile.intl'], [], ['com.rarlab.rar', 'com.kreditpintar', 'com.whatsapp']]
df = pd.DataFrame({"No":No, "app_list":app_list})
###########################################

# Best practice: vectorial way, given by @mozway
df['Count'] = df['app_list'].str.len()


# Alternative: list comprehension way, by me:
df["Count"] = [len(x) for x in df.app_list]
```

Output:

```
    No  app_list                                         Count
0   1   [com.lenovo.anyshare.gps, com.UCMobile.intl]      2
1   2   []                                                0
2   3   [com.rarlab.rar, com.kreditpintar, com.whatsapp]  3
```

Comment: If you have lists: `df['Count'] = df['app_list'].str.len()` is the vectorial way to do it ;)

Comment: I have a blind spot for this and always default to list comprehension. Yours obviously makes more sense and reads better. I will update my answer to include both but prioritize yours.